# MySQL : Timestamps replicating inconsistently depending on local timezone of server?

Tags: mysql, replication, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-timestamp

can anyone explain mysql 5.5 handling of replication between two
servers.

This is a structure of one of my table.

```
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'NULL' AUTO_INCREMENT
kot_no varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL'
emp_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY DEFAULT '0'
description varchar(45) NULL DEFAULT 'NULL'
created_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
created_by int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
modified_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
modified_by int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT '0'
state tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
```

In my database every table has last 5 columns and my binlog format is `STATEMENT BASED REPLICATION`

When I'm executing `INSERT INTO kot (kot_no, emp_id, created_date) VALUES (1, 1, NOW())` on Server A these are the results on two servers.

on SERVER A

```
id  kot_no  emp_id  description  created_date         created_by  modified_date        modified_by  state
1   1       1       null         2015-11-01 22:51:57  0           2015-11-01 22:51:57  0            1
```

on SERVER B

```
id  kot_no  emp_id  description  created_date         created_by  modified_date        modified_by  state
1   1       1       null         2015-11-02 12:21:57  0           2015-11-02 12:21:57  0            1
```

I had naively assumed that dates would always be stored in UTC in the
database and the only effect of localtime would be for display
purposes? Can anyone shed some light on what's happening here and tell me solution for this without affecting server data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `MySQL timezone` is different in both server

check your timezone for this query :-

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

or you can set timezone like that :-

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';//your timezone 
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';////your timezone 
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';////your timezone
```

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but both of server timezone are set as `SYSTEM` I just executed `SELECT NOW()` and both server timezone are exactly same.

Comment: yeah, my localtime zone is UTC+05:30

Comment: i think you need to change your MySQL timezone in both server

Comment: yeah, you are right. it solves my problem. thnk you so much